# I am getting "Network Error: connection timeout" error

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I am getting network error: connection timeout in my amazon AWS instance after i run

```
sudo ufw enable
```

command. please help how can I login again to my server.

Comment: Need to use `sudo ufw allow` to allow ports you want to be able to use.

Comment: But i am not able login to putty. where should i run this command

Comment: I think this should be helpful: https://intellipaat.com/community/8740/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-with-ufw-in-ec2-aws